# Configure SELinux to allow qemu/virt-manager and samba to both read/write to the same folder?

Tags: fedora, virtual-machine, qemu, selinux, libvirt

#### Problem summary

I have a local folder that is shared under samba but if I try to allow qemu (via user session) to access it via virtio-9p, I get an error (SELinux avc). Works fine with SELinux disabled but I would like to get it working *with* SELinux. Please help.

#### Background

On a Fedora host, I have both samba and virt-manager/qemu installed. Both work fine independently of each other (e.g. samba dirs and vm dirs completely different paths, not even on same drive).

For a new project I'm working on, I would like to find a way to allow both virt-manager/qemu and samba (possibly also docker/podman) to have access to an existing host folder currently shared by samba while still restricting access as much as possible. My understanding is that accessing the share over `smb://` protocol, while possible, will incur some i/o lag due to network overhead, even if both are on the same host. To this end, I am hoping to avoid `smb://` protocol altogether and have the VM locally accesss the shared host folder via virtio-9p or something similar. Also, to clarify, this is not a remote samba share that is locally mounted but rather a local folder that is shared out to other computers on my lan.

Per some [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-managing_confined_services-samba-booleans), I found a boolean that I thought might allow my VM to access files under the `samba_share_t` context:

> **virt_use_samba**      Allow virtual machine access to CIFS files.

Since I had previously configured the folder using samba file contexts:

```
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro=1;
# setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw=1;
# setsebool -P samba_share_fusefs=1;
  
# sambaShare=/media/d/shared
# semanage fcontext --add --type "samba_share_t" "${sambaShare}(/.*)?"
# sudo restorecon -R "${sambaShare}";
```

Everything works fine from the samba side of things and I can read/write there without any issues.

Today, I set the new boolean, thinking that this would let the VM do so as well

```
# setsebool -P virt_use_samba=1
# getsebool -a | grep -P '(smb|cifs|samba|virt_|emu).*on$'
samba_export_all_ro --> on
samba_export_all_rw --> on
samba_share_fusefs --> on
virt_sandbox_use_all_caps --> on
virt_sandbox_use_audit --> on
virt_use_nfs --> on
virt_use_samba --> on
virt_use_usb --> on
xend_run_qemu --> on
```

but I am still getting an error. Given that I already had a Windows VM on this host that was able to access samba shares via `smb://` protocol **prior** to setting this variable.. I am not sure if `virt_use_samba` is intended to allow VMs to access to the protocol but Windows just does things differently, if it is intended to allow VMs to access folders with the `samba_share_t` file context but for some reason it isn't working correctly for me, or if it has been deprecated / does something else entirely. I also rebooted my system after setting the variable, just to rule that out but it made no difference whatsoever.

I already tested and the setup works when temporarily using `setenforce 0` - I am able to add the Filesystem via VM settings then mount it in the VM, even write to it without any issue. But once I turn SELinux back on, I can't even start the VM anymore - I get an error and have to remove the virtio-9p filesystem entry before I can even launch again.

---

#### Error and Config Details

##### System

```
# inxi -Sz
System:
  Kernel: 6.6.6-100.fc38.x86_64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/0
    Distro: Fedora release 38 (Thirty Eight)
         
# dnf list installed selinux-policy
Installed Packages
selinux-policy.noarch                   38.30-1.fc38                    @updates
```

I also run virt-manager/qemu under a user (e.g. `qemu:///session`) rather than a root (e.g. `qemu:///system`) if that makes any difference. I set this via `gsettings`, e.g.

```
gsettings set org.virt-manager.virt-manager.connections uris "['qemu:///session']";
gsettings set org.virt-manager.virt-manager.connections autoconnect "['qemu:///session']";
```

##### virtio-9p config

* Note: I'm actually configuring this manually via virt-manager gui but this is the xml that gets generated. The actual process I am doing is (from virt-manager), I open the VM dialog and go to the details tab, then choose the 'Add Hardware' button in the lower-left > Filesystem > driver=virtio-9p, define source and target paths > Finish button. Then once the VM is started, I mount using: `mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio "${virtualPath}" "${guestMountPoint}"` where virtualPath is the target path defined in the xml below and guestMountPoint is whatever path on the guest OS (e.g. `/media/shared`).

```
<filesystem type="mount" accessmode="mapped">
  <source dir="/media/d/shared"/>
  <target dir="/virtio-9p/shared"/>
</filesystem>
```

##### Error from virt-manager messagebox:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2023-12-17T04:07:05.237139Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device {"driver":"virtio-9p-pci","id":"fs1","fsdev":"fsdev-fs1","mount_tag":"/virtio-9p/shared","bus":"pci.2","addr":"0x0"}: cannot initialize fsdev 'fsdev-fs1': failed to open '/media/d/shared': Permission denied'
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2008, in _do_async_install
    installer.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 695, in start_install
    domain = self._create_guest(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 637, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(initial_xml or final_xml, 0)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4481, in createXML
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2023-12-17T04:07:05.237139Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device {"driver":"virtio-9p-pci","id":"fs1","fsdev":"fsdev-fs1","mount_tag":"/virtio-9p/shared","bus":"pci.2","addr":"0x0"}: cannot initialize fsdev 'fsdev-fs1': failed to open '/media/d/shared': Permission denied
```

##### Error from SELinux:

```
# ausearch -m avc -ts boot
----
time->Sat Dec 16 23:07:05 2023
type=AVC msg=audit(1702786025.235:319): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=4221 comm="qemu-system-x86" name="shared" dev="dm-4" ino=83951617 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:svirt_t:s0:c98,c936 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

---

#### Questions:

I understand the issue is that my VM does not have access to the `samba_share_t`. From the research I have done so far, it sounds like there are several options available:

1. I've seen hints online that it might be possible to modify rules but never any commands/tutorials for actually doing so  (e.g. "to add missing access rules for already existing file type" in [this discussion](https://centosfaq.org/centos/how-to-have-more-than-on-selinux-context-on-a-directory/)). **Assuming that modifying an existing SELinux ruleset, such as to allow qemu/svirt_t/etc access to the 'samba_share_t' file context, could anyone show me a simple example of how to do this? Or, if it is more involved than I am thinking, even a brief 10,000 ft overview and a link would be greatly appreciated**. I am still learning my way around SELinux and haven't had a formal education so please bear in mind that I do not have access to any paid RH knowledge portals and the public RH docs aren't always the clearest. I found a [SELinux page on the Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux) which is where I'm planning to try next (thought to ask here first tho since I'm not sure which section to focus on and there's a LOT to read).
2. I've seen a few mentions online that one can change the file context of the dir to `public_context_rw_t` and set a selinux boolean to allow access. I think I would need `setsebool -P smbd_anon_write=1` (or [maybe](https://serverfault.com/questions/275619/allowing-multiple-types-in-the-type-field-of-a-folder-label-in-selinux) `setsebool -P allow_smbd_anon_write 1`?) to allow samba to access this context. But all of the examples I found were for more popular services like httpd and I am utterly clueless what the name of the boolean I need to set for qemu/virt-manager (or docker/podman) is called. I don't see anything similarly named in `getsebool -a` output. I am also somewhat hesitant to use this approach since it seems like this would allow other services access to that folder as well. **Assuming I go with this approach, what booleans would I need to set for qemu and docker/podman?**
3. I am open to other serious options (e.g. not interested in "turn off SELinux" as a solution).

If there's any other relevant info needed for a solution, please let me know.